# Explain the output of following C++ Program

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

Help me to understand the code
explain me what comes in array *p[].
Shouldn't the array be addresses of all elements of A.
Explain the printf statement output.

```
main( )
{
    static int  a[ ]   = {0,1,2,3,4};
    int  *p[ ] = {a,a+1,a+2,a+3,a+4};
    int  **ptr =  p;
    ptr++;
    printf(" %d  %d  %d\n", ptr-p, *ptr-a, **ptr);
    *ptr++;
    printf(" %d  %d  %d\n", ptr-p, *ptr-a, **ptr);
    *++ptr;
    printf(" %d  %d  %d\n", ptr-p, *ptr-a, **ptr);
    ++*ptr;
    printf(" %d  %d  %d\n", ptr-p, *ptr-a, **ptr);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
1 1 1 
2 2 2 
3 3 3 
3 4 4
```

Comment: Are you asking why there is a `3` for the 1st item in the 4th line?

Comment: I don't think you've copied the program correctly. C++ doesn't allow curly quotes around strings, they should be ASCII doublequotes.

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question, so we know which part of it you don't understand. Do you know what `printf` does? Do you understand what the `%d` format means? Do you understand how array initialization works?

Comment: @WeatherVane I think she asks how carriage returns went to the output

Comment: Please explain how output to ptr-p, *ptr-a, **ptr and other print statement comes ?

Comment: Strictly: `printf("%d\n", ptr-p)` is undefined behavior as the type of a pointer difference is `ptrdiff_t`, not `int`, so code should be `printf(" %td  %td  %d\n", ptr-p, *ptr-a, **ptr);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an int array, int * array and int **.

Now, checking `ptr - p` is checking what is the difference between where ptr points and where p points (how much int chunks are between). `*ptr-a` checks what is the difference between the addresses pointed by *ptr (a pointer by itself) and a, and at last `**ptr` checks the value of the array in the location pointed by `*p`.

Since you move the pointers like this: `*++ptr, *ptr++, ptr++` then the the pointer points to farther location so the output grows.

The last increment `++*ptr` works on the value of `p`, not of `ptr` so the `ptr - p` remains the same

Comment: how    **ptr= 1 in first print statement  ?

Comment: ptr++ is executed, then ptr points to (*ptr + 1) which is a+1, and p points to a, so the address of a+1 minus the address of a is 1*sizeof(int), and because ptr is int** it prints 1

Comment: *ptr contains base address of *p[].when ptr is incremented,it contains address of first element of p which is address of 1.'a' contains the base address of  array a[].So when address of first element of array - base address of array output should be 1*sizeof(int).size of int is 4 in my compiler. How come the answer is 1 then in   printf(" %d",*ptr-a)

Comment: sizeof(int) is 4, but what the compiler sees is you check by how much one int pointer differs from another int pointer. If you counts the bytes, you get 4 bytes, but since the compiler knows the type is int, it converts it to "how many instances of the pointee type are? " the type is int, and the number is 1

Comment: Thanks,I understood..please explain how does ++*ptr works  ?..please explain

Comment: *++ptr means you increment the pointer and then dereference it. The * is not relevant since no one tries to check the value of it in that line so it has the same meaning as ++ptr. I recommend you would look in here (http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) for more detailes

Comment: Thanks a lot,you are a great  teacher